# Unique_ptr c++ usage

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Sincerelly i m not so expert with c++ RAII features. I never used before. Anyway i m begining to study about it (i m in "kernel panic").  Compiling a module i have the following error :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::reset(_Up) [with _Up = char*; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = const char; _Dp = std::default_delete<const char []>]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:539:9:   required from ‘typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__and_<std::is_array<_Up>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::_Pointer::type, _Tp*>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type*>, std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type (*)[], _Tp (*)[]>, std::__or_<std::__and_<std::is_reference<_Dp>, std::is_same<_T2, _U2> >, std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_reference<_Dp> >, std::is_convertible<_Ep, _Dp> > > >, std::is_assignable<_T2&, _U2&&> >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = char []; _Ep = std::default_delete<char []>; _Tp = const char; _Dp = std::default_delete<const char []>; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__and_<std::is_array<_Up>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::_Pointer::type, _Tp*>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type*>, std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type (*)[], _Tp (*)[]>, std::__or_<std::__and_<std::is_reference<_Dp>, std::is_same<_T2, _U2> >, std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_reference<_Dp> >, std::is_convertible<_Ep, _Dp> > > >, std::is_assignable<_T2&, _U2&&> >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&>::type = std::unique_ptr<const char []>&]’
java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:33:58:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(const char*&, char*&)’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:179:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> >::value>::type std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&)
     swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:179:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘const char*’ and ‘char*’)
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:202:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> typename std::enable_if<std::__is_swappable<_Tp>::value>::type std::swap(_Tp (&)[_Nm], _Tp (&)[_Nm])
     swap(_Tp (&__a)[_Nm], _Tp (&__b)[_Nm])
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:202:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘_Tp [_Nm]’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:471:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> void std::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     swap(pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:471:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5287:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> void std::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     swap(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5287:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/array:275:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> void std::swap(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/array:275:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1546:5: note: candidate: template<class ... _Elements> void std::swap(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
     swap(tuple<_Elements...>& __x, tuple<_Elements...>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1546:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::tuple<_Elements ...>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:2238:5: note: candidate: template<class _Res, class ... _Args> void std::swap(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)
     swap(function<_Res(_Args...)>& __x, function<_Res(_Args...)>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:2238:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::reset(_Up) [with _Up = char*; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = const char; _Dp = std::default_delete<const char []>]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:539:9:   required from ‘typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__and_<std::is_array<_Up>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::_Pointer::type, _Tp*>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type*>, std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type (*)[], _Tp (*)[]>, std::__or_<std::__and_<std::is_reference<_Dp>, std::is_same<_T2, _U2> >, std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_reference<_Dp> >, std::is_convertible<_Ep, _Dp> > > >, std::is_assignable<_T2&, _U2&&> >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = char []; _Ep = std::default_delete<char []>; _Tp = const char; _Dp = std::default_delete<const char []>; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__and_<std::is_array<_Up>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::_Pointer::type, _Tp*>, std::is_same<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type*>, std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::element_type (*)[], _Tp (*)[]>, std::__or_<std::__and_<std::is_reference<_Dp>, std::is_same<_T2, _U2> >, std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_reference<_Dp> >, std::is_convertible<_Ep, _Dp> > > >, std::is_assignable<_T2&, _U2&&> >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&>::type = std::unique_ptr<const char []>&]’
java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:34:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(const char*&, char*&)’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:179:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> >::value>::type std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&)
     swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:179:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘const char*’ and ‘char*’)
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:202:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> typename std::enable_if<std::__is_swappable<_Tp>::value>::type std::swap(_Tp (&)[_Nm], _Tp (&)[_Nm])
     swap(_Tp (&__a)[_Nm], _Tp (&__b)[_Nm])
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h:202:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘_Tp [_Nm]’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:62,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:471:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> void std::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     swap(pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:471:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5287:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> void std::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     swap(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5287:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/array:275:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> void std::swap(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/array:275:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/functional:55:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1546:5: note: candidate: template<class ... _Elements> void std::swap(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&, std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
     swap(tuple<_Elements...>& __x, tuple<_Elements...>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1546:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::tuple<_Elements ...>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:79:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:2238:5: note: candidate: template<class _Res, class ... _Args> void std::swap(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)
     swap(function<_Res(_Args...)>& __x, function<_Res(_Args...)>& __y)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/functional:2238:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from ./java/./rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.h:13,
                 from java/rocksjni/comparatorjnicallback.cc:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:614:6: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’ and ‘std::__tuple_element_t<0ul, std::tuple<const char*, std::default_delete<const char []> > > {aka const char*}’
  swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
```

I m not sure to understand this stack trace but it seams there is a mismatch in the unique_ptr . Maybe const char* and char*.

the class where there is the bug is :

```
    CompactionFilterFactoryJniCallback::CompactionFilterFactoryJniCallback(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject jcompaction_filter_factory)
    : JniCallback(env, jcompaction_filter_factory) {

  // Note: The name of a CompactionFilterFactory will not change during
  // it's lifetime, so we cache it in a global var
  jmethodID jname_method_id =
      AbstractCompactionFilterFactoryJni::getNameMethodId(env);
  if(jname_method_id == nullptr) {
    // exception thrown: NoSuchMethodException or OutOfMemoryError
    return;
  }

  jstring jname =
      (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(m_jcallback_obj, jname_method_id);
  if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    // exception thrown
    return;
  }
  jboolean has_exception = JNI_FALSE;
 // line 33
  m_name = JniUtil::copyString(env, jname, &has_exception);  // also releases jname
  if (has_exception == JNI_TRUE) {
    // exception thrown
    return;
  }

  m_jcreate_compaction_filter_methodid =
      AbstractCompactionFilterFactoryJni::getCreateCompactionFilterMethodId(env);
  if(m_jcreate_compaction_filter_methodid == nullptr) {
    // exception thrown: NoSuchMethodException or OutOfMemoryError
    return;
  }
}

const char* CompactionFilterFactoryJniCallback::Name() const {
  return m_name.get();
}

std::unique_ptr<CompactionFilter> CompactionFilterFactoryJniCallback::CreateCompactionFilter(
    const CompactionFilter::Context& context) {
  jboolean attached_thread = JNI_FALSE;
  JNIEnv* env = getJniEnv(&attached_thread);
  assert(env != nullptr);

  jlong addr_compaction_filter = env->CallLongMethod(m_jcallback_obj,
      m_jcreate_compaction_filter_methodid,
      static_cast<jboolean>(context.is_full_compaction),
      static_cast<jboolean>(context.is_manual_compaction));

  if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    // exception thrown from CallLongMethod
    env->ExceptionDescribe();  // print out exception to stderr
    releaseJniEnv(attached_thread);
    return nullptr;
  }

  auto* const cff = reinterpret_cast<CompactionFilter*>(addr_compaction_filter);

  releaseJniEnv(attached_thread);

  return std::unique_ptr<CompactionFilter>(cff);
}
```

It is not clear how to read this stack trace for identifying the problem. I would appreciate to receive a little suggestion for understand how fix the problem and read the stack trace.

Comment: Which line is line 33? What is the type of `m_name`?

Comment: What’s the definition of the `CompactionFilter` class? If you weren’t using `unique_ptr` and you were finished using the `CompactionFilter` you created this way, how would you get rid of it?

Comment: Please narrow the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: std::unique_ptr<const char[]> m_name;

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you have a `std::unique_ptr<char const[]>` object on which you try to call function `reset` passing `char*` as an argument.

Well, that argument needs to be `char const*` for that to compile, which you can achieve with a `const_cast`, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<char const[]> p;
char* q = new char[1]{};
p.reset(const_cast<char const*>(q));
```

---

Looks like `JniUtil::copyString` returns `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` and you assign it to `std::unique_ptr<char const[]>` which causes the error.

One fix is to change the type of `m_name` to be `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Another is to manually add constness (adding constness is safe and is an implicit conversion, but is needed here to choose the correct overload of [`std::unique_ptr<>::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset)):

```
m_name.reset(const_cast<char const*>(JniUtil::copyString(...).release()));
```

Comment: `const_cast` is very, *very* rarely the correct solution.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you think about the `const_cast` here, it is adding constness, rather than removing it, which is perfectly safe and is an implicit conversion.

Comment: m_name.reset( const_cast<char * const>( JniUtil::copyString(env, jname, &has_exception)));  // also releases jname --->java/rocksjni/compaction_filter_factory_jnicallback.cc:34:90: error: invalid const_cast from type ‘std::unique_ptr<char []>’ to type ‘char* const’
   m_name.reset( const_cast<char * const>( JniUtil::copyString(env, jname, &has_exception)));  // also releases jname

Comment: @BiancaMattiolo Updated the answer for you, note `release` call in there.

Comment: static std::unique_ptr<char[]> copyString(JNIEnv* env, jstring js,
        jboolean* has_exception) {

Comment: @BiancaMattiolo That's what I suspected.

Comment: static std::unique_ptr<char[]> copyString(JNIEnv* env, jstring js,
        jboolean* has_exception)  ... it seams be the right way ... thanks for the help. I began to understand how to read stack trace in c++ :) Anyway template usage in c++ it is a bit complex :) i have to make exercise a lot :)